# Controlling animation-duration (given by user input) via jQuery

Tags: jquery

**Problem:** There is no direct way to control the animation-duration of a CSS3 Keyframes animation via jQuery.

**Link**: https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/yoZxMr

**Plausible/Failed Attempts:** I've tried something like                                $(".parent").css("animation-duration", newimg), but this fails to work. There is also the method of adding/subtracting a class with the property of animation duration, controlled by an event (i.e, click of the "Done" button).

**Context**: In my web app, https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/yoZxMr, I have a "Speed" setting, which can be found if the mouse is hovered on the left sticky sidebar.

**Goal:** The user should be able to insert a value into a text field. Clicking done, will trigger an event which changes the animation duration of the spinning wheel to that value, making it spin faster/slower. Unfortunately, the methodology below, of adding and subtracting a child class from the parent does not work for my code.

Furthermore, there were no errors in the console which appeared to due the jQuery code shown below, thus, it may be a formatting issue. Any help is appreciated; Thank you.

Current jQuery for the functionality:

```js
$('.speedSave').click(function() {
    var el = $('.parent').addClass('custom');
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.removeClass('custom');
    }, 1000);
 var newimg = $(this).val();
                      $(".parent").css("animation-duration", newimg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: let me see if I understood. You have a wheel spinning slowly and clicking you want 3s of fast spinning, right?

Comment: Close; There is a text field, where the user will input a number _such as_ 3s. Pressing done will trigger an event that changes the animation duration of the spinning wheel to the given value (3s, in this case).

Comment: @Rayman This is definitely a GSAP issue. GSAP is fast and easy to learn. Their plugin TweenMax should be applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can better achieve what you want with [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/docs/TweenMax) by GSAP.

Here below a working example (run the snippet).

It has also a fallback if user doesn't set anything on the input field.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  TweenMax.to('#spinner', 10, { 
    rotation: 360,
    repeat: -1,
    ease: Linear.easeNone,
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '#button', function(){

  var duration = parseInt( $('#duration').val() );
  if ( isNaN( duration ) ) 
    { duration = 1 }

  TweenMax.to('#box', duration, { 
    rotation: '+=360',  
    ease: Power3.easeInOut });
})
```

```css
#spinner {
  display: inline-block;
}
#box {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spinner">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>

Add  fast spin duration (seconds):
<input type="text" name="duration" id="duration">
<button id="button">Rotate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use GreenSock (TweenMax) for this. https://greensock.com

I have modified your example with gsap, if you change the number of seconds in the speed input it changes the rotation speed.

Here is the js for it:

```
var rotationSpeed = 3,
        TimeLine = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});

$('.speedSave').click(function() {
    rotationSpeed = $(".speedtext").val();
    TimeLine.duration(rotationSpeed);
});

TimeLine.to(".rcc", rotationSpeed, {
    rotation:-360,
    transformOrigin:"center",
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    force3D: true,
});

TimeLine.to(".parent", rotationSpeed, {
    rotation:360,
    transformOrigin:"center",
    ease: Power0.easeNone,
    force3D: true,
}, "-=" + rotationSpeed);
```

And here is your modified example:
https://codepen.io/lyimmi/pen/brzQZY/